# Unable to catch dioerror [dioerrortype.response]: http status error [statusCode]

Tags: node.js, json, express, flutter, multer

dioerror [dioerrortype.response]: http status error [statusCode]

Here is the Headers part :

```
Headers("Authorization": "token", 
        "Content-Type" : "multipart/form-data", 
        "Accept" : "application/json")
```

Here is The Data part :

```
    try {
      FormData data = FormData.fromMap({
        "username": userName.toString(),
        "name": naMe.toString(),
        "birthday": birthDay.toString(),
        "about": aboutUser.toString(),
        "sender": sendUser.toString(),
        "mobile": userMobile.toString(),
        "avatar": _image != null
            ? await MultipartFile.fromFile(_image.path,
                filename: avatarName.toString())
            : Text('Invalid Avatar'),
      }); 
     }
```

Here is Dio request/response part :

```
try {
     Dio dio = Dio();
     dio.options.headers['Accept'] = "multipart/form-data";
     dio.options.headers['Authorization'] = "Bearer $token";
     dio.options.headers['Content-Type'] = "application/json";

     var response = await dio.post(url, data: data);
     final res = json.encode(response.data);
     print('$res');
     var responseCode = response.statusCode;
     print('$responseCode');
 }
```

Comment: Welcome! Quick suggestion: If you change your title so its a question and show your code along with the error you will get more people to help.

Comment: In the first block you use multi part form; in the second JSON? Which is correct? You don't show what `data` is. Are you able to connect to the server using Postman or similar?

Comment: In postman I got right reply. & In postman their is only two headers one is Authorization and the second is Content-Type : application/json

Comment: Is this happen for the multipart header....??

Comment: The problem was solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by editing catch blog with

```
On DioError catch (error) {
   var statusCode = error.response.statusCode;
   Print(statusCode);
}
```